# import numpy error: undefined symbol: zgelsd_

Tags: ubuntu, numpy

System info: ubuntu 14.04, python3.4, numpy1.11.3

I installed numpy using **sudo apt-get install python3-numpy**, but when I try to **import numpy**, it went wrong as follows:

import numpy
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "", line 1, in

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/numpy/**init**.py", line 142, in   from . import add_newdocs

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/numpy/add_newdocs.py", line 13, in     from numpy.lib import add_newdoc

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/numpy/lib/**init**.py", line 18, in   from .polynomial import *

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/numpy/lib/polynomial.py", line 20, in  from numpy.linalg import eigvals, lstsq, inv

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/numpy/linalg/**init**.py", line 51, in    from .linalg import *

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/numpy/linalg/linalg.py", line 29, in 
    from numpy.linalg import lapack_lite, _umath_linalg

**ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/numpy/linalg/lapack_lite.cpython-34m.so: undefined symbol: zgelsd_**

What's wrong with my installation?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/8697. Finally, I installed Anaconda instead. It worked well.